# First order logic Prolog anonymous variables

Tags: prolog, first-order-logic, prolog-anonymous-variable

The Prolog rule below:

```
grandparent(X,Z) :- parent(X,Y) , parent(Y,Z)
```

In first order logic is going to be:

```
∀x ∀y ∀z ((P (x, y) ∧ P (y, z)) → G(x, z))
```

In theory if we have an anonymous variable in our Prolog rule something like:

```
grandparent(X,Z) :- parent(X,Y, _ ) , parent(Y,Z, _ )
```

Lets say it is a surname, how can we present it in first order logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the rule:

> *"Give the child a name"*

Note that the underscore is *not* a single variable. Two underscores in Prolog have nothing to do with each other.

We can simply replace the code with:

```
grandparent(X,Z) :-
    parent(X,Y,A),
    parent(Y,Z,B).
```

And now a logical "*equivalent*" would be:

∀x ∀y ∀z ∀a ∀b: ((P (x, y, a) ∧ P (y, z, b)) → G(x, z))

Note however that the two are **not equivalent**: since theoretically speaking (probably not here), the first `parent/3` call, might have side effects, ground terms further, etc. Only a subset of Prolog maps to such logical constructs.